# Speeding a video with kdenlive, then slowing it down

Tags: kdenlive

I am using `kdenlive` to speed up a video.  Then I want to play it back, slowing it down to be as the original.  It is a way to have smaller files.  But the sound is all funny, even when I make the video slower.  What settings should I use?